# Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE is laggy on 4k monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde, performance, 4k-monitor

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma on a dual boot with Windows 10. I use a total of 3 different monitors, two being Full HD, and one 4k. My system uses an AMD Ryzen 3700x CPU, 16GB RAM and an NVIDIA 1060 6GB GPU.

I'm having bad performance on my 4k monitor. Opening applications or moving and resizing them causes lags and the animation is "cut off"; really laggy. Games (Cities Skyline, Stardew Valley), however, are running smoothly. On Windows 10 these problems do not occur. Also, this should not be a hardware problem performance-wise, since my system's specs are quite good.

Do you have any ideas what may cause this problem and what I can do against it?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone also encounters this problem: I was not able to fix it. It seems that there is a bug when using an NVIDIA graphics card with [Aurorae](https://techbase.kde.org/User:Mgraesslin/Aurorae) window decorations.

I've noticed that I only had issues when I was using literally any other theme in KDE plasma than Breeze or Breeze dark. So I simply switched to using Breeze and now everything's working great.

Comment: Do you have a link to a bug report?

Comment: No, I solely came across a reddit post in r/kde a few months ago if I remember correctly. I can try to find it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Wahou crazy, the same here, it was very laggy for the Overview effect. I switched back to Breeze and it's fixed!